# Is this strategy to avoid unnecessary reads from firestore mobile client good?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Is this strategy to avoid unnecessary reads from firestore mobile client good?
First fire the query on the cache. Note down the time of last modified document. Fetch documents from server modified after that time.

Whenever data need to displayed follow above sequence. This way cache gets build incrementally.

Comment: Does it work for you?  Then it's good. Question seeking opinion like this are off topic for Stack Overflow and likely to be [closed](https://overflow.tips/why-question-closed).

Comment: Yes, it will work. Besides that, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e) will also help.